# iOS UIImage Passes Old Image

Tags: ios, uiimageview, segue

In my app, Im using an API to get images from a server. Using the below code, it gets the images in order of size to replace themselves with better quality.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[[self.information objectForKey:@"images"]objectForKey:@"normal"] description]]];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
    self.shotImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    self.image.image = self.shotImage;
});

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[[self.information objectForKey:@"images"]objectForKey:@"hidpi"] description]]];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    self.image.image = self.shotImage;
});
```

Also, if you press on the image it then takes you too another ViewController where the image is fullscreen.

However, even if I wait for the high quality one to load before I tap on it, in the PrepareForSegue Method, it still only passes the original low quality version.

See code below from PrepareForSegue

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    FullSizeImageViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] init];
    img = self.shotImage;
    vc.shotImage = img;   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[[self.information objectForKey:@"images"]objectForKey:@"hidpi"] description]]];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    self.image.image = self.shotImage;
});
```

In this code looks like you miss this line:

```
self.shotImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Comment: nope, the updating of the image works fine, its just passing the image

Comment: Yes. But you pass self.shotImage is segue, but not update it when get new image

Comment: And as you can see, you update it when get low tes value

Comment: I mean when you got low resolution value you set self.shotImage, and then pass it to segue, but you don't update it in second block.